# listview adding footer, header and item from bottom

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to deal with the following scenarion with no luck :(
I want to build the following listview:

```
"--------------------"

  header


< empty space >

< empty space >

< empty space >

< empty space >





  item1

  footer

"-------------------"
```

and between the header to the footer I don't want to have anything, just black nadda.
is it possible? thanks

Comment: You should try posting what you have tried and where you have failed, in order for others to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must understand how it works.
Header and Footer (hereinafter referred to as HF) - a View, which can be added to the list above and below. For ensuring the appropriate View list items are no longer meets the adapter and programmer. He has to create a View and submit it to the list in the methods or addHeader addFooter.

These are two methods of implementation. Consider the example of Header.

1. **addHeaderView (View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable)**

v - View, which is displayed as a list item
data - the object associated with the item list
isSelectable - will it be possible to click on the item or release him

1. **addHeaderView (View v)**

There simply is a challenge of the first method with the following parameters: addHeaderView (v, null, true);

When using HF and the adapter has a caveat. When assigning a list adapter (method setAdapter), a list of checks that were already added to Header or Footer.

If not, the list is active then it prohibits the adapter itself to further enhance HF. It is written in the help of methods and addHeader addFooter - «Call this before calling setAdapter». That is, you have to add the HF before assign the adapter list.

If so, the list wraps the resulting adapter HeaderViewListAdapter, using the constructor: HeaderViewListAdapter (ArrayList  headerViewInfos, ArrayList  footerViewInfos, ListAdapter adapter), where headerViewInfos and footerViewInfos - it previously added to the list of HF, and the adapter - the adapter that we give the list. And now at work list will be used by the adapter HeaderViewListAdapter, ie will be used as HF, and the data from the adapter, which is assigned the list.

So if you run the sample code below

```
  lvMain.addHeaderView(header1);
    lvMain.addHeaderView(header2, "some text for header 2", false);
    lvMain.addFooterView(footer1);
    lvMain.addFooterView(footer2, "some text for footer 2", false);
    lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
```

you will get a listview with 2headers,2footers and you're adapter below headers & footers.

**For you problem :**
Yes this is possible in several cases :

- You're adapter inflated blank view
- You're in data in adapter is a " " or something like this
- Youre inflated view have black text on black background, but in that case you may be watching this on click.

**For the future - Post your code and use tags for the text box so that we can fully identify the problem**